# How to raise an exception from another class

Tags: python, oop

I have the following predefined code:

```
class WeekDayError(Exception):
    pass
    

class Weeker:
    #
    # Write code here
    #

    def __init__(self, day):
        #
        # Write code here
        #

try:
    weekday = Weeker('Monday')
    print(weekday)
except WeekDayError:
    print("Sorry, I can't serve your request.")
```

My task is now to fill in the code so that if Monday is entered the exception is raised and the print statement is printed to the screen.

I tried the following:

```
class WeekDayError(Exception):
    pass
    

class Weeker:
    list=["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"]

    def __init__(self, day):
        if day not in Weeker.list:
            WeekDayError()
try:
    weekday = Weeker('Monday')
    print(weekday)
except WeekDayError:
    print("Sorry, I can't serve your request.")
```

However, when I run my code the exception is not raised. Where is my mistake?

I can see that the object information is printed. The statement containing the exception `class WeekDayError` with the pass is given, so this is not to be modified. So the mistake must be in what I have written here:

```
if day not in Weeker.list:
    WeekDayError()
```

But as far as I can see the condition is true (Monday is not in the list) so the WeekDayError() class is called.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`raise` it:

```
def __init__(self, day):
    if day not in Weeker.list:
        raise WeekDayError()
```

Comment: Perfect, I will accept your answer in 12 minutes. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do not use `list=["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"]` - use   `weekdays=["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"]` - You shadow the built-in `list` . See https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html